# Set systemd journalctl to ignore process

Tags: systemd

My `journalctl` is littered with `gnome-session` warnings. I've tracked down the issue to Google Chrome, and the warning is relatively harmless. However, it's flooded my journal output, and frankly I won't be able to find what I need if I do need to check it.

`May 30 12:13:49 hostname gnome-session[1347]: Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.`

Frankly, it's a Chrome issue and I'll leave it at that. But is there a way to make the `journalctl` command suppress output from a certain process? I'd like to just disable `gnome-session` logging altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question seems like it would be a better fit on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsystemd%5d%20journal).

Regardless though, being able to **filter out** units when perusing logs can easily be done piping to `grep -v` even when *following* (with grep's `--line-buffered` param) like

```bsh
journalctl -f | grep --line-buffered -v "gnome"
```

That still sucks because now there is no helpful coloring. Constructing the command arguments for journalctl gives a much nicer experience.

```bsh
JARGS=`journalctl -F _COMM | sed -e 's/gnome.*//' -e 's/^/_COMM=/' | xargs`
journalctl -a -f $JARGS
```

Now follow works as nicely as paging while hiding gnome lines in less using `$!gnome`. **Woot!**

**<sub>It is a shame systemctl and journalctl don't allow regex matching for inclusion/exclusion.</sub>**

---

On a personal use system (which I'm guessing your on because of the gnome-session annoyance) there are a few settings that may be useful to setup.

Edit the system [`journald.conf`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) to

1. Split the log by boot.
   verify `Storage=` **persist** or **auto** (default).
   and create `sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal`
2. Limit storage use by time.
   `MaxRetentionSec=1week`

Reboot to effectively restart the systemd-journald.service.

Then you can use

```bsh
journalctl -a -b -f $JARGS # -b to limit to current boot
```

or whatever args you desire without the unwanted gnome-session stuff.

Comment: When using the `$JARGS` trick (with `gnome` being filtered out for instance), the `kernel` records aren't shown unfortunately. Any suggestions? (By kernel record I mean for instance: `Dec 15 21:59:17 service-ad-1-1.localdomain kernel: RTNL: assertion failed at net/core/net_namespace.c (187)`)

Comment: Agree with @Thell "its a shame" no regex on --unit selection or possible feature journalctl --unit-exclude is annoying.

Comment: Interesting - journalctl gnu mashup piped to journalcti with a variable. Like grep piped to grep :)